# Mocking methods of local scope objects with Mockito

Tags: object, mocking, local, mockito

I need some help with this:

Example:

```
void method1{
    MyObject obj1=new MyObject();
    obj1.method1();
}
```

I want to mock `obj1.method1()` in my test but to be transparent so I don't want make and change of code.
Is there any way to do this in Mockito?

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The answer from @edutesoy points to the documentation of `PowerMockito` and mentions constructor mocking as a hint but doesn't mention how to apply that to the current problem in the question.

Here is a solution based on that. Taking the code from the question:

```java
public class MyClass {
    void method1 {
        MyObject obj1 = new MyObject();
        obj1.method1();
    }
}
```

The following test will create a mock of the `MyObject` instance class via preparing the class that instantiates it (in this example I am calling it `MyClass`) with `PowerMock` and letting `PowerMockito` to stub the constructor of `MyObject` class, then letting you stub the `MyObject` instance `method1()` call:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @Test
    public void testMethod1() {      
        MyObject myObjectMock = mock(MyObject.class);
        when(myObjectMock.method1()).thenReturn(<whatever you want to return>);   
        PowerMockito.whenNew(MyObject.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(myObjectMock);
        
        MyClass objectTested = new MyClass();
        objectTested.method1();
        
        ... // your assertions or verification here 
    }
}
```

With that your internal `method1()` call will return what you want.

If you like the one-liners you can make the code shorter by creating the mock and the stub inline:

```java
MyObject myObjectMock = when(mock(MyObject.class).method1()).thenReturn(<whatever you want>).getMock();
```

Comment: Problem with this approach if i use EclEmma for code coverage is that EclEmma gives 0% code coverage for MyClass if i add MyClass.class into @PrepareForTest instead of the actual code coverage. I think this is a limitation or bug with EclEmma tool. Any idea to overcome this issue?

Comment: @Vidyasagar I Found the same Issue in Sonar/Jacoco.

Answer (score 34):

If you really want to avoid touching this code, you can use [Powermockito](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki) (PowerMock for Mockito).

With this, amongst many other things, you can [mock the construction of new objects](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki/MockConstructor) in a very easy way.

Comment: Note taken, but for future use I will use PowerMock

Comment: @edutesoy Can you write full code? I cannot understand your idea. I don't see relation between constructor mocking and local variabli mocking.

Comment: Problem with this approach if i use EclEmma for code coverage is that EclEmma gives 0% code coverage for MyClass if i add MyClass.class into @PrepareForTest instead of the actual code coverage. I think this is a limitation or bug with EclEmma tool. Any idea to overcome this issue?

Answer (score 20):

No way. You'll need some dependency injection, i.e. instead of having the `obj1` instantiated it should be provided by some factory.

```java
MyObjectFactory factory;

public void setMyObjectFactory(MyObjectFactory factory)
{
  this.factory = factory;
}

void method1()
{
  MyObject obj1 = factory.get();
  obj1.method();
}
```

Then your test would look like:

```java
@Test
public void testMethod1() throws Exception
{
  MyObjectFactory factory = Mockito.mock(MyObjectFactory.class);
  MyObject obj1 = Mockito.mock(MyObject.class);
  Mockito.when(factory.get()).thenReturn(obj1);
  
  // mock the method()
  Mockito.when(obj1.method()).thenReturn(Boolean.FALSE);

  SomeObject someObject = new SomeObject();
  someObject.setMyObjectFactory(factory);
  someObject.method1();

  // do some assertions
}
```

Comment: This is what I have in mind, but this is adding more unnecessary code because I need to mock a method from local scope object.

Comment: I don't want to create Factory in order to create new instances of myObject and that code is unnecessary because it's only needed in order to mock method of local scope variable.

Comment: You got to have a factory in order to have a fresh instance of `MyObject` whenever `method1` is invoked

Comment: @Boris Pavlović Hi Boris, I find your answer very interesting,And I am trying to apply it to one of my examples which is very similar to this issue. But I cant manage to make the test pass. Could you have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15350239/breaking-a-local-dependency-to-unit-test-a-void-method I appreciate if you could give me some tip, on  what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @sfrj it seems that tallseth has already answered correctly (http://stackoverflow.com/a/15352255/32090)

Answer (score 12):

Both mocking of a new instance creation and static methods is possible without PowerMock in the latest mockito versions and junit5.

Take a look in the methods `Mockito.mockConstruction()` and `Mockito.mockStatic()`.

In your case:

```javascript
try (MockedConstruction<MyObject> myobjectMockedConstruction = Mockito.mockConstruction(MyObject.class,
        (mock, context) -> {
            given(mock.method1()).willReturn("some result"); //any additional mocking
        })) {
    underTest.method1();
    assertThat(myobjectMockedConstruction.constructed()).hasSize(1);
    MyObject mock = myobjectMockedConstruction.constructed().get(0);
    verify(mock).method1();
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Great update provided by Mockito.

Answer (score 3):

You could avoid changing the code (although I recommend Boris' answer) and mock the constructor, like in this example for mocking the creation of a File object inside a method. **Don't forget** to put the class that will create the file in the `@PrepareForTest`.

```java
package hello.easymock.constructor;

import java.io.File;

import org.easymock.EasyMock;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.easymock.PowerMock;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;
    
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({File.class})
public class ConstructorExampleTest {
        
    @Test
    public void testMockFile() throws Exception {

        // first, create a mock for File
        final File fileMock = EasyMock.createMock(File.class);
        EasyMock.expect(fileMock.getAbsolutePath()).andReturn("/my/fake/file/path");
        EasyMock.replay(fileMock);

        // then return the mocked object if the constructor is invoked
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = new Class[] { String.class };
        PowerMock.expectNew(File.class, parameterTypes , EasyMock.isA(String.class)).andReturn(fileMock);
        PowerMock.replay(File.class); 
    
        // try constructing a real File and check if the mock kicked in
        final String mockedFilePath = new File("/real/path/for/file").getAbsolutePath();
        Assert.assertEquals("/my/fake/file/path", mockedFilePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you don't prefer to use PowerMock, you may try the below way:

```
public class Example{
...
void method1(){
    MyObject obj1 = getMyObject();
    obj1.doSomething();
}

protected MyObject getMyObject(){
    return new MyObject();
}
...
}
```

Write your test like this:

```
@Mock
MyObject mockMyObject;

@Test
void testMethod1(){
    Example spyExample = spy(new Example());
    when(spyExample.getMyObject()).thenReturn(mockMyObject);
    //stub if required
    doNothing().when(mockMyObject.doSomething());
    verify(mockMyObject).doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating a factory method in MyObject:

```
class MyObject {
    public static MyObject create() {
      return new MyObject();
    }
}
```

then  mock that with [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/).

However, by mocking the methods of a local scope object, you are depending on that part of the implementation of the method staying the same.  So you lose the ability to refactor that part of the method without breaking the test.  In addition, if you are stubbing return values in the mock, then your unit test may pass, but the method may behave unexpectedly when using the real object.

In sum, you should probably not try to do this.  Rather, letting the test drive your code (aka TDD), you would arrive at a solution like:

```
void method1(MyObject obj1) {
   obj1.method1();
}
```

passing in the dependency, which you can easily mock for the unit test.

Comment: I would go for this solution. As adding the tested class in @PrepareforTest results to no coverage in jacoco or eclemma which has been an issue with powemock. Glad I had saw this! Thank you! 