# How to verify a non-mocked method was called?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, verify, method-call

I want to test that my method calls another method in the *same class* that I cannot mock.

**Example:**

```
public void methodToTest(){

//other stuff to test that can be mocked
someClassICanMock.doSomething();

//method within same class that cannot be mocked
methodFromSameClassIWantToVerify();

}
```

How can I use a `verify` to check that this my method under test calls `methodFromSameClassIWantToVerify();?`

Edit: not a duplicate as I am specifically refers to how to test this using mockito.

Comment: Sounds like you want a spy, like shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33670427/1743880

Answer (score 11, accepted):

like this,

```
MyClass c = new MyClass(); 
someClassICanMock  m = mock(someClassICanMock.class);
doNothing().when(m).doSomething();
MyClass s = spy(c);
s.methodToTest();
verify(s , times(1)).methodFromSameClassIWantToVerify();
```

Comment: thanks, so this wont actually run the code inside the method?

Comment: it will, spy allows you to inspect calls on actual instances

Comment: ok, is there a way to call spy to see that the method was invoked, but not actually call the code inside it?

Comment: verify(s , times(1)).methodFromSameClassIWantToVerify();