# Mockito mocking a call to a constuctor in a private method

Tags: constructor, mockito

In a class I'm testing, there is a private method that instantiates the GetRequest class in Unirest. How do I use Mockito so that the instantiation of GetRequest class in getResponse() results in a mock object that I use in my JUnit test?

```
public ClassUnderTest {
    public String methodToTest() {
        String url = "http://localhost:8080";
        String result = getResponse(url);
        return result;
    }

    private String getResponse(String url) {
        GetRequest getRequest = new GetRequest(HttpMethod.GET, url);
        ... = getRequest.header(...).headers(...).asJson();
        ...etc...
    }
}
```

Thank you,
Rico

Comment: ...etc... really ?? And where is your work. Did you try anything ?

Comment: Tried looking in Mockito website and googling. After several hours of no success I thought I would pose a question here and then proceed to do more research. I will post an answer if I find a solution that works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mockito : how to verify method was called on an object created within a method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841623/mockito-how-to-verify-method-was-called-on-an-object-created-within-a-method)

Answer (score -1):

One solution is to use a partial mock as in [Use Mockito to mock some methods but not others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14970516/use-mockito-to-mock-some-methods-but-not-others?rq=1). I can refactor the call to the constructor in a private method and mock that.