# How to verify an internal method call using Powermock?

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to use PowerMockito to test a save method by verifying an internal *audit()* method call.
This internal call is made by *auditor* object which is being instantiated in an *init()* method of the class. As it is not injected I will not be able to mock it directly. When I used Mockito to verify it always said "There were zero interaction with the mock".
Question:How exactly do I test the save feature? Kindly help!

```
public class DaoImpl implements Dao{
private Auditor auditor;

@InjectValue
private ObjectLoader loader;

@InjectValue
private ConfigurationProvider confProvider;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    //Mock this object instantiation and verify audit is called once
    auditor = new SyncAuditor(confProvider.getClientConfiguration(), new EventRegProvider());
}

@Override
public void save(final AuditEvt auditEvt) {
  final AuditedEvent auditedEvent = builder.build();
  auditor.audit(auditedEvent); 
 }
```

Test :

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ DaoImplTest.class })
@PowerMockIgnore("javax.management.*")
public class DaoImplTest extends PowerMockito {

@InjectMocks
private DaoImpl dataAccess;

@Mock
private SynchAuditor auditorMock;
 @Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    loader = ObjectLoader.init("JUNIT");
    loader.bind(ConfigurationProvider.class, configurationProviderMock);
    dataAccess = loader.newInstance(DaoImpl.class);
}

@After
public void tearDown() {
    loader.release(dataAccess);
    ConnectionMgr.disconnect("JUNIT");
}

@Test
public void testSaveAuditEvent() throws Exception { 
     PowerMockito.whenNew(SynchAuditor.class).
     withArguments(Matchers.any(ClientConfiguration.class), Matchers.any(EventRegProvider.class)).thenReturn(this.auditorMock);
     final AuditEvent event = AuditEvent.from(null, "principal", UUID.randomUUID().toString(), "randomText",
            new AuditEvtDefn((long) 522, "234242", "234242fdgd", true), SUCCESS, null, new GregorianCalendar());
     dataAccess.save(event);
     Mockito.verify(auditorMock, times(1)).audit(Matchers.any(AuditedEvent.class));
}
```

Even PowerMockito.verifyNew says there were zero interaction
`PowerMockito.verifyNew(SynchronousAuditor.class,times(1)).withArguments(Matchers.any(AuditorClientConfiguration.class),Matchers.any(EventRegistrationProvider.class));`

Comment: PS: I can not use DI or Factory pattern. Also, I followed this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841623/mockito-how-to-verify-method-was-called-on-an-object-created-within-a-method?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I figured out that java reflection will help in such a situation. You will have to get hold onto the real object and then set mocked object to it.

```
final Field privateAuditorField = DaoImpl.class.getDeclaredField("auditor");
privateAuditorField.setAccessible(true);
privateAuditorField.set(dataAccess, auditorMock);
```

Now verify will run sucessfully.

`Mockito.verify(auditorMock, Mockito.times(1)).audit(Matchers.any(AuditedEvent.class));`