# [JUnit][Mockito] How to verify method was called another level down the call stack?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I have `MyClass` that has `OtherClass` as a field:

```
public class MyClass
{
    @Autowired
    private OtherClass other;
    public void foo() {
        // Some interactions
        other.bar(someParameter);
    }
}

public class OtherClass
{
    public void bar() {
        // Some interactions
        if (someConditionThatIsTrue) {
            baz(someParam);
        }
    }

    public void baz(SomeParamClass param) {
        // Some interactions
    }
}
```

For testing `MyClass`, I want to check that `OtherClass.baz()` was called from `MyClass.foo()`. This is what I have:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {
    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;
    @Mock
    private OtherClass otherClass;

    @Test
    public void testFoo_whenFooIsCalled_shouldTriggerBaz() {
        // Some setups
        myClass.foo();
        verify(otherClass, times(1)).baz(any());
    }
}
```

The test above doesn't detect `OtherClass.baz()`, but detects `OtherClass.bar()` :

```
Wanted but not invoked: otherClass.baz( <any> ); -> at MyClassTest.testFoo_whenFooIsCalled_shouldTriggerBaz(MyClassTest.java:12) However, there were other interactions with this mock: otherClass.bar( "some parameter" ); -> at MyClass.foo(MyClass.java:7)
```

Without [refactoring `MyClass`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841623/mockito-how-to-verify-method-was-called-on-an-object-created-within-a-method), is it possible to detect the instance of `OtherClass.baz()` from  the test?

Comment: There was no call to `baz`. Your `OtherClass` instance is a mock so it does not run the code from your implementation.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Is the current solution a bad practice for unit testing design? What would you recommend as an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use a spy

```
@Spy
private OtherClass otherClass;
```

However, this isn't a great practice. You're testing two distinct classes. I would just make sure you make the call to `bar` in your first test with the correct param. Then create a separate unit test file for `OtherClass`.