# Testing void methods that do not change anything in Test scenario

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, junit, mockito

I know that every method that doesn't do anything shouldn't be tested (or not even exist). The thing is, that my method does something normally, but for the test-scenario I have to mock that thing that it does. But I would still like to assert the parameters that it would send to the external thing.

Sounds more complicated than it is - Check my snippet for better understanding:

```
class A {
    @Inject
    private Mailer mailer; // Custom mailer class

    public void doSomething() {
        Date date = new Date(); // dynamic parameter I do not care about in the test
        String parameter = "test"; // The parameter I want to test later

        mailer.sendMail(parameter, date);
    }
}

class ATest {
    @Mock
    @Produces
    private Mailer mailer;

    @Inject
    private A classToTest;

    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() throws Exception {

        classToTest.doSomething();

        assertThat(??).isEqualTo("test"); //How can I get the value of parameter?
    }
}
```

As you can see I need to mock my emailer, so that I dont send a email everytime a test runs.

It would make no sense to promote `parameter` to a global variable.

Is there any way to test the value of `parameter` without changing the code of `A`? And if not what would be the best solution without messing up my class just for testing?

Comment: mock your mailer and test that mailer.sendMail(x) has been called

Comment: @Stultuske My mailer is mocked and I need the value of `parameter` to test. Not just if it got called

Comment: so check whether it is called with that parameter.

Comment: Thats what Im trying to figure out. Haven't found anything like that on SO. @Stultuske

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841623/mockito-how-to-verify-method-was-called-on-an-object-created-within-a-method

Comment: Thats not the same scenario @Stultuske.

Comment: yes, it is. it's just a level deeper.Now, you can say it's not the same scenario, but then why would you accept an answer that tells you exactly the same?

Comment: My question was "How can I access the result of a void that gets sent to a mocked thing". He answered that. That other StackOverflow post doesnt do that. It just tells me how to verify that it got called (which I would have had other ways for too) @Stultuske

Comment: A void has no return value thats right, but it can result in something (in this example it results in a sent email). The link you posted did not solve that problem I had. Thank you for your help and concerns though.

Comment: you can't test that, you can only test that the method was called and no exception was thrown. The answer you accepted doesn't test more than that: just that the method is called, and what you passed as parameter.

Comment: `parameter == the result` just to clarify it for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Mockito.verify`:

```
verify(mailer, times(1)).sendMail("test");
```

Verify checks what happened with your mocks: how many times a method was called, and what arguments were given to that method.

---

Update:
If you want to exclude certain parameters, you can use `org.mockito.Matchers.any` - easier to have it as a static import. (NB: if you do ignore some parameters, then the ones you want to INCLUDE now have to be wrapped in `org.mockito.Matchers.eq`).

```
verify(mailer, times(1)).sendMail(eq("test"), any(Date.class));
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I actually have multiple parameters for sendMail and one of them is the current `Date`. How can I verify that `parameter == "test"`, but ignore the date? I updated my question with a example.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you! I will mark it as accepted, but one small question though: can you do something like `eqContains("te")`?

Comment: nevermind I found it pretty quick now that I know about this. its just `Matchers.contains()`.

Comment: You can also look at `ArgumentCaptor`.  Lets say your parameter was a complex Object, with lots of fields - rather than a simple String.  You can use an `ArgumentCaptor` to capture the object that was given to your mock, and inspect it afterwards. That's much more powerful, but overkill for simple checks like this

Comment: Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

One way is to parameterize the method `doSomething` with a **mutable object**, that you can set upon method execution and assert in the test method. Otherwise, you may also check for exception thrown for any negative scenario, something like

```
@Test(expected = EmailSendException.class)
public void testDoSomething(){
    ....
}
```

Comment: this is a horrible plan. what if something else causes such an Exception to be thrown? do understand they are trying to test a happy flow, not an exception

Comment: Emailer is mocked, so it wont throw anything. I could manually throw something, but that still wouldnt let me check the result of `parameter`.