# How can I test if a method was called on an object created inside the method to be tested

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

Is it possible to test that the "innerMethod" was called without modifying the Class class?

I need to make a unit test in a separate class both scenario of the "someCondition".

The problem is that the method is void so I cannot make use of the return type. The only way would be to check if the "innerMethod" was called.

I was thinking to use Mokito verify but this method is called inside a method on an object created at runtime.

Any suggestion is most welcome.

```
public class Class {

     public void outerMethod(outerObj) {

          if(someCondition) {

               Object innerObj = new Object();
               innerObj.innerMethod(outerObj); 

          } else {

               //other code
          }    
}
```

Comment: You could Mock the Object class, and check using Mockito

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841623/mockito-how-to-verify-method-was-called-on-an-object-created-within-a-method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the use of `Mockito::times` and `Mockito::verify` methods.

test setup would be as follows:

```
@InjectMocks
private SomeService service;

@Mock
private SomeHelper helper;
```

and then test that some method from the helper has been involved in the following manner:

```
@Test
public void testInnerHasBeenCalledOnce() throws Exception {

    service.outherMethodName(someParam);

    Mockito.verify(helper, Mockito.times(1)).innerMethodName(someParamSecond);
}
```

Comment: @VictorCalin Could you accept the answer if you find it a match.

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) -> accept an answer (if it is the most appropriate though).