# Mockito when method not working

Tags: java, mockito

I am using mockito as mocking framework. I have a scenerio here, my when(abc.method()).thenReturn(value) does not return value, instead it returns null.

```
public class DQExecWorkflowServiceImplTest {
@InjectMocks
DQExecWorkflowServiceImpl dqExecWorkflowServiceImpl = new DQExecWorkflowServiceImpl();
@Mock
private DQUtility dqUtility;
@Mock
private DqExec dqExec;
@Mock
private DqCntlDefn dqCntlDefn;
@Mock
private DqCntlWfDefn dqCntlWfDefn;
@Mock
private DqCntlWfDefnTyp dqCntlWfDefnTyp;
@Mock
private IDQControlWfDefTypeService controlWfDefTypeService;

@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    dqExec = new DqExec();
    dqCntlWfDefn = new DqCntlWfDefn();
    dqUtility = new DQUtility();
    dqCntlWfDefnTyp = new DqCntlWfDefnTyp();
    dqCntlWfDefnTyp.setDqCntlWfDefnTypCd("MIN_INCLUSIVE_VAL");
    dqExecWorkflowServiceImpl
            .setControlWfDefTypeService(controlWfDefTypeService);

}

@Test
public void testExecuteWorkflow() {
    when(controlWfDefTypeService.getDqCntlWfDefnTypCd(dqCntlWfDefn))
            .thenReturn(dqCntlWfDefnTyp);
    dqExecWorkflowServiceImpl.executeWorkflow(dqExec, dqCntlWfDefn);
}
```

}

**Java class**

```
@Override
public DqCntlWfExec executeWorkflow(final DqExec dqExec,
        final DqCntlWfDefn dqCntlWfDefn) {
final DqCntlWfExec dqCntlWfExec = new DqCntlWfExec();
dqCntlWfExec.setDqCntlWfExecEffDt(dqUtil.getDefaultEffectiveDt());
dqCntlWfExec.setDqCntlWfExecExpDt(dqUtil.getDefaultExpiryDt());
dqCntlWfExec.setDqCntlWfDefn(dqCntlWfDefn);
dqCntlWfExec.setDqExec(dqExec);

final DqCntlWfDefnTyp dqCntlWfDefnTyp = controlWfDefTypeService
    .getDqCntlWfDefnTypCd(dqCntlWfDefn);
     String workflowType = null;
if(null!=dqCntlWfDefnTyp){
    workflowType = dqCntlWfDefnTyp.getDqCntlWfDefnTypCd();
}
```

When ever i run the test file the when is not working and i am using mockito1.8.5 jar in the buildpath. The service call is being mocked but returns the null value.

```
final DqCntlWfDefnTyp dqCntlWfDefnTyp = controlWfDefTypeService
    .getDqCntlWfDefnTypCd(dqCntlWfDefn);
```

This object dqCntlWfDefnTyp is null

I have done this before and there was no problem with the when, It seems to be working with files i have done before. I had followed the same procedure for the test file but i couldnt figure out the issue. Can anyone please assist me

Thanks to all the folks in advance

Comment: Try reducing this to a smaller example, it's pretty unreadable. And I sure hope those names aren't under your control, because there is simply no excuse for `setDqCntlWfExecEffDt`. Note especially how inconsistent the code is in whether to use an abbreviation or not: `setDqCntlWfExecEffDt` vs `getDefaultEffectiveDt`, `executeWorkflow` vs `DqCntlWfExec`, etc. Seriously, the code could be submitted to TheDailyWTF as is.

Comment: The code has been refactored and made it readable

Comment: Can you add the error/output? How do you know it's `null`? Are you inferring it from `workflowType`... could it be that `.getDqCntlWfDefnTypCd()` is returning `null`? Etc... FWIW, I think the original code may hold the key to this. :-)

Comment: I am adding the whole set, since i could miss some information.

Comment: Why would somebody use such naming UN-convention. Some people just want to watch the world burn..

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Mockito mock works when we mock the objects loosely.

Here is the change i have made to make it work:

```
when(controlWfDefTypeService.getDqCntlWfDefnTypCd(any(DqCntlWfDefn.class))
    .thenReturn(dqCntlWfDefnTyp);
```

Instead of passing the object of the Mock class, I passed the class with the Matcher `any()` and it works.

Answer (score 34):

**TL;DR** If some arguments in your test are `null`, be sure to mock the parameter call with *`isNull()`* instead of *`any(SomeClass.class)`*.

---

**Explanation**

This might not be the answer that helps OP, but might be useful for someone else. In my case the setup was all good, however, some mocks returned the desired `thenReturn(...)` value and some didn't.

It's important to understand, that the method call you're trying to mock (i.e. the method in `when(someMock.methodToMock)`) has to match **the actual call *and not* the signature only**.

In my case, I mocked a method with a signature:

```
public void SomeValue method(String string, SomeParam param)
```

The call however, in the test was something like:

```
method("some string during test", null);
```

Now if you mock the call with:

```
when(MockedClass.method(anyString(), any(SomeParam.class))
```

Mockito will not match it even though the signature is correct. The problem is that Mockito is looking for a call of `method()` with the arguments `String` and `SomeParam`, whereas the actual call was with a `String` and **`null`**. What you have to do is:

```
when(MockedClass.method(anyString(), isNull())
```

---

**Hint**

Since there are many `isNull()` implementations in different frameworks, be sure to use this one `org.mockito.ArgumentMatchers.isNull`.

Comment: you are a real hero without a cape

Comment: Yup SECONDED!... Not all heroes wear capes!... just using `any()` covered both real object argument and null for me. I needed this answer to get some direction on why my mock wasn't behaving like I expected it to, especially when null was passed

Comment: This answer saved me my day!

Answer (score 11):

I had the same problem. The solution for me was to put the Mockito.when(...).thenReturn(...); into the @Before-SetUp method.

Answer (score 8):

I think I have found your issue, but not all the credit goes to me.

Since you are trying to mock 'dqCntlWfDefnTyp' in your test class and the object itself is being instantiated in the class that you are trying to test, you inevitably run into some issues. The primary problem is that the object cannot be mocked because it is being recreated in during the test.

There are a few options, but the best choice in my humble opinion is using [PowerMockito](https://github.com/jayway/powermock/wiki). You will be able to replace the object within the class that is being tested with the one you mock.

An excellent example of this usage of PowerMockito from @raspacorp on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30633175/4930850):

```
public class MyClass {
void method1{
    MyObject obj1=new MyObject();
    obj1.method1();
}
}
```

And the test class...

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(MyClass.class)
public class MyClassTest {
@Test
public void testMethod1() {      
    MyObject myObjectMock = mock(MyObject.class);
    when(myObjectMock.method1()).thenReturn(<whatever you want to return>);   
    PowerMockito.whenNew(MyObject.class).withNoArguments().thenReturn(myObjectMock);

    MyClass objectTested = new MyClass();
    objectTested.method1();

    ... // your assertions or verification here 
}
}
```

Comment: when I do `objectTested = new MyClass();` spring still uses it's own created instance and does not honor the one configured in Test. Is there any way to work around this ?

Answer (score 3):

Just like [Younes EO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59209588/1993204) said: it usually is related to `null` arguments being passed to mocked functions.

One thing worth adding is that if you're using Kotlin for your tests (and you have `mockito-kotlin` in your project), for `Nullable` arguments you should **usually** use `anyOrNull()` instead of `any()`.

Answer (score 0):

Relevant to the topic, just in case this helps someone. My `mockito.when` wasn't working when asserting `anyString()` reason being the `String` within the tested class was an injected value from a properties file. The following line set the injected value in the unit test:

```
ReflectionTestUtils.setField(bean, "theVariable", "theValue");
```

Answer (score 0):

I haved the same problem when i make test for controler. Use @MockBean instead @Mock

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a method that i forgot to mock:
When i mocked a method, a parameter i passed it was another method call, which i should've mocked to, otherwise it was passing null and it didn't work.
So i mocked:

`when(testService.create(any(VTestData.class), anyBoolean())).thenReturn(new VData())`

But inside the service this method was implemented like:

`VData vData = testService.create(adapter.from(data), true)`

So: `adapter.from(data)` was not mocked, and it was passing as null, so it couldn't recognized as a mocked service bcs it was receiving null instead of an object.