# Can i mock static method whith juni5 and mockito or easymock?

Tags: mocking, mockito, easymock

I need to mock a static method with junit5 **(that's is very important)** and mockito or easymock.
I saw that powermock works only with junit 4.
there exists any form to do it with junit5?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Junit5 mock a static method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830441/junit5-mock-a-static-method/63242611#answer-63242611)

Comment: Basically, [It is possible from version Mockito 3.4.0 without extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830441/junit5-mock-a-static-method/63242611#answer-63242611)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mocking of static methods is not possible without PowerMock. And when you need PowerMock, it means that the code is not developed correctly, in the way it is testable. I am working on a project with Java 11, JUnit 5 and Mockito. PowerMock does not support this at all. And I doubt it will ever support it.

That being said: the only way to make it testable is to have the class-with-static-method injected into the class you need to test and then replace the implementation of the bean in the test-scope with a mock. When you inject it, you have a live object, so no need for a static method anymore.

It has benefits to change the code and use an injection framework (like Spring). I know there are situations you can't just do this. If you really can't change the implementation, just leave this for what it is and make a lot of unit tests to test the static method by itself with all kind of parameters. Just to make sure this class works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Not from as far as I know. The easiest will be to shield it with a non-static method.

```
public class A {
    void foo() {
        Stuff s = MyClass.getStuff();
    }
}
```

will become

```
public class A {
    private final StuffProxy stuffProxy;
    public A(StuffProxy stuffProxy) {
        this.stuffProxy = stuffProxy;
    }
    public A() {
        this(new StuffProxy());
    }
    void foo() {
        Stuff s = stuffProxy.get();
    }
}

public class StuffProxy {
    public Stuff get() {
        return MyClass.getStuff();
    }
}
```

Then you mock `StuffProxy`.