# How to write JUnit TestClass for ConnectionPool config Class

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, microservices

How to write a JUnit test class for the below class?
While I am trying to write I was getting
`"Cannot locate declared field com.bs.proteo.microservices.channels.sessionmobileadapter.business.openam.resource.ConnPoolConfig.connPoolRouteSize"` error.

```
public class ConnPoolConfig {

    @Bean(name = "openAmHttpClient")
    public HttpClient buildConnectionPool(
            @Value("${login.connectionpool.route.size:10}") int connPoolRouteSize,
            @Value("${login.connectionpool.size:10}") int connPoolSize,
            @Value("${login.connectionpool.ttl:60}") int connPoolTtl,
            @Value("${login.connectionpool.evictidle:30}") int connPoolEvictIdle,
            @Value("${connection.http.timeout.connection.request}:5000") int connRequestTimeout,
            @Value("${connection.http.timeout.connect:5000}") int connectTimeout,
            @Value("${connection.http.timeout.socket:30000}") int socketTimeout){

        RequestConfig config = RequestConfig.custom()
                .setConnectionRequestTimeout(connRequestTimeout)
                .setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout)
                .setSocketTimeout(socketTimeout)
                .build();

        final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                .disableCookieManagement()
                .setMaxConnPerRoute(connPoolRouteSize)
                .setMaxConnTotal(connPoolSize)
                .setConnectionTimeToLive(connPoolTtl, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .setDefaultRequestConfig(config)
                .evictIdleConnections(connPoolEvictIdle, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();

        return httpClient;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different alternatives. In the example below I will use only few lines referred to `HttpClientBuilder`, but you can use the same mechanism everywhere in your code.

**Using Power Mockito**

You can use [PowerMockito](https://powermock.github.io/) in order to mock the first static call.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({HttpClientBuilder.class})
public class MyJunit{
    
   @Test
   public void myTest() {
      HttpClientBuilder client = Mockito.mock(HttpClientBuilder.class);
      PowerMockito.when(HttpClientBuilder.create()).thenReturn(client);
      myclassUnderTest.buildConnectionPool(...);
      Mockito.verify(client).disableCookieManagement();

   }
}
```

PowerMockito has some disadvatages; for example:

1. your tests will slow down due the overhead needed to override the static methods
2. if you use [JaCoCo](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco) in order to keep track of your code coverage, then it won't work anymore.

**Refactor your code**

The only difference here is to avoid to use PowerMockito and refactor your class under test in a test friendly manner.
The point here is to wrap the static method calls with protected methods; then we will mock all of this methods just created in order to return a mock object useful to verify the settings time by time.

Let's add a method like this to your class under test

```
 protected HttpClientBuilder create(){
    return HttpCLientBuilder.create();
 }
```

Now, your test method will be something like this

```
 @Test
 public void myTest(){
    HttpClientBuilder client = Mockito.mock(HttpClientBuilder.class);
    Mockito.doReturn(client).when(myclassUnderTest).create();
    myClassUnderTest.buildConnectionPool(...);
    Mockito.verify(client).disableCookieManagement();
}
```

Comment: Nice answer, but necessary to mention that PowerMockito is not available for Junit5 - but fortunately plain old Mockito from version 3.4.0 has mocking static methods including for Junit5.   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830441/junit5-mock-a-static-method