# How to mock static methods in Junit 5?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito, junit5, junit-jupiter

I read a few threads here about static methods, and I think I understand the problems misuse/excessive use of static methods can cause. But I didn't really get to the bottom of why it is hard to mock static methods in JUnit 5.

I know in JUnit 4 we can do it using PowerMockito but how to do it in Junit 5? An easy explanation/link would be great.

My use case:
I've created a service class in which I'm calling static method of other class. But that value is returning as Null.

So, I need some reference by which I can mock that static method so that I can continue writing test case for same.

JUnit 5 dependencies in pom.xml:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>5.8.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Here is a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830441/junit5-mock-a-static-method

Answer (score 0):

This is for [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/) using [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org/) language:

```kotlin
class MyTests {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BeforeAll
        fun init() {
            mockkStatic(MyClassContainingStaticFunction::class)
        }
        @JvmStatic
        @AfterAll
        fun finish() {
            unmockkStatic(MyClassContainingStaticFunction::class)
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `My unit test`() {
        // Here, the static method has been mocked
        every { MyClassContainingStaticFunction.theFunction() } returns "hello"
    }
}
```

And here is a solution using [MockK](https://mockk.io/) library:

```kotlin
class MyTests {
    companion object {
        @JvmStatic
        @BeforeAll
        fun init() {
            mockkStatic(Myclass::itsFunction)
        }
        @JvmStatic
        @AfterAll
        fun finish() {
            unmockkAll()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `My unit test`() {
        // Here, the static method has been mocked
        every { Myclass.itsFunction() } returns "Hello"
        // ...
    }
}
```