# using Mockito, doReturn() calling original method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, spy

I am trying to partial mock on a local variable. Then trying doReturn() so that it does not calls the original method. However it does call the original method.

Here is my doReturn statement

```
@Spy
ReportFileWriter iReportFileWriter = new ReportFileWriter(Any.stringNotNull(), Any.stringNotNull());

@Mock
Environment environment;

@InjectMocks
IDataSync iDataSync ;

@Test
public void testRunTask() {
    doReturn(Any.stringNotNull()).when(iReportFileWriter).writeResult(any(List.class), any(Date.class));

    iDataSync.someMethod(readParameters, false);
}
```

`Any` is a custom class providing dummy values.

`Any.listContactRecords()` returns a dummy list of type `List<ContactRecords>`

`ContactRecords` is a custom class

result.contactRecords is of type :

```
public List<ContactRecord> contactRecords;
```

and startDateTime is :

```
public Date startDateTime;
```

In the code in test report file writer is a **local** variable, defined as

```
public someMethod(){
  ReportFileWriter iReportFileWriter = new ReportFileWriter(environment.getProperty("reports.tempFileDir"), environment.getProperty("reports.fileNameFormater.i")) ;

  fullFilename = iReportFileWriter.writeResult(result.contactRecords, taskParameter.startDateTime);
.
.
.
}
```

However, writeResult should have not been called. It is neither final nor static.

I should be able to get a return value according to [Mockito: Trying to spy on method is calling the original method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method/11620196)

and

I should be able to spy on local variable according to :

[Using Mockito to mock a local variable of a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236338/using-mockito-to-mock-a-local-variable-of-a-method)

Comment: Why aren't you using argument matchers when you specify the when condition? You should be using "eq(whatever)" or "any()" or similar.

Comment: I did a quick change to writeResult(eq(Any.listContactRecords()), any(Date.class))

Didn't help

Comment: Could you please show a complete code of your test method?

Comment: Perhaps that was not your only problem, but it was a problem. Ivan is right. You aren't showing enough code to figure out what exactly you are doing wrong. Where do you create the spy?

Comment: @Dave I added the code where I am creating a spy.

Comment: @BhavyaArora, could you please also add whole test method? Your `someMethod()` from above doesn't use mock created with spy.

Comment: @Ivan I updated the code above, see if it makes more sense now and if you need anything more?

Comment: If you use local variable `iReportFileWriter` in your `IDataSync.someMethod()` then `@InjectMocks` will not help. You need to change `IDataSync.someMethod()` to either to use a property of `IDataSync` object or to accept instance of `iReportFileWriter` as a parameter

Comment: Yeah, I get you. I am creating a property of IDataSync. As I feared that this might be your answer and might be no way to create a mock of a local variable through partial mocking.