# Unable to mock the local variable inside a method in java

Tags: junit, mockito

I'm new to testing, using mockito and junit for testing. The class along with the test method looks like this.
Edit: Made corrections to the method.

```
class SomeClass
{

   Data data;
   public Data method1(int n1, int n2)
   {

        data = method2(n1, n2);

        if (data != null && data.something()!=null  && !data.something().isEmpty()) 
        {
          // other instructions
        }
        return data;
   }
   Data method2(int n1, int n2)
   {
       Data data1 = Some calculations;
       return data;
   }
}

//Test class


@Mock
Data data;


@Test
public void testData()
{
    @Test 
    public void getReceivingDataTest() 
    {
        
        SomeClass mock = Mockito.spy(new SomeClass.class);
        when(mock.method2(1,1)).thenReturn(data);
        mock.method1(1,1);
    }
}
```

Here I'm trying to set the value for the received data from the method2 from the test method, but unfortunately I'm not able to mock the local variable ***Data data***. It calls the real method method2 and gets a null value and throws a null exception. I have tried using mock instead of spy and i get the same error. What do i do?
edit: method2() is calling another service which since im mockinf it, always returns null and the "other instructions" inside method1() are not executed.

Comment: This does not even compile: 1. `Mockito.spy(new SomeClass.class)`. 2. You call `method2(n1, n2);` while `method2` takes no args 3. @Test on class is not applicable.
Please make an effort to post the code that reproduces your problem

Comment: Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236338/using-mockito-to-mock-a-local-variable-of-a-method

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies, i made the changes,  maybe its understandable now? sorry im new to stackoverflow

Comment: @alea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620103/mockito-trying-to-spy-on-method-is-calling-the-original-method this worked. thanks