# Local objects impact on Mocking

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, tdd

Ive recently entered into the world of mocking using jMock - in particular mocking in regards to db. Ive read some posts on how its not possible to (easily) mock a local object contained in a class / method. As Ive never actually done any proper TDD / mocking, Ive always defined objects such as 'ResulSet' in my methods where appropriate. Therefore my question is, when Im going forward with future DB classes / methods, should I define ResultSet as a field, and then have an appropriate Setter Method as a means to access it for testing?

If I should, is this still reasonable considering I probably wouldnt use this setter method for anything else but testing?

Essentially, am I to define all objects with setter methods to aid mocking?

I saw this post: [Mocking methods of local scope objects with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520242/mocking-methods-of-local-scope-objects-with-mockito) and it seems to suggest what Ive said above is acceptable.

I know it seems like a basic question, but I dont want to form bad habits early on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have in the post that you've mentioned is not a good way to go. I suggest starting your TDD adventure without mocking. Start with test-first approach and you will end up with design, which does not require such hideous testing (e.g. partial mocking). Then start mocking, but remember: only mock what you own (so if ResultSet is a JDBC class, you definately should not mock it).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be mocking at that level. Basically the idea is that you have interfaces that acts as a facade on database and ORM operations.

```
interface IFetchUsers {
   UserList GetAll();
   User GetById(int id);
}
interface ICalculateDebt {
   float GetDebt(int accountId);
}
interface IPersistOrder {
   void Save(Order order);
}
```

(forgive syntax errors, it's been a long time since I've done Java.)

These are injected via the constructor into your other classes and become trivial to [mock, or even stub](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html).

Then, for actual db code you just implement these interfaces. You can even put all implementations in a single class.

And that's it. No need to get fancy, but if you do want to get into fancier versions of this look into the repository design pattern (though I would argue that its not really necessary if using a good ORM).