# Mocking method for all instances of class with PowerMockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

I am trying to mock a method whatever the instance that calls this method is. As far as I could got reading this can't happen with Mockito and should be done with PowerMockito, but I can't figure out the way it should be done.
I have

```java
public class B{
    public void veryAnnoyingMethod(int i, short s){}
}
public class A{
    public void veryImportantMethod(){
        B newB = new B();
        newB.veryAnnoyingMethod(i,s);
        ...
    }
}
```

I am trying to test the `veryImportantMethod()` and want to mock the `veryAnnoyingMethod()`.
I don't want to mock the constructor as explained here: [Mocking methods of local scope objects with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520242/mocking-methods-of-local-scope-objects-with-mockito) because apart from the `veryAnnoyingMethod()` I need the `newB` fully functional.

I have come up with something like:

```java
B dummyB = PowerMockito.spy(new B());
PowerMockito.doReturn(null).when(dummyB.veryAnnoyingMethod(Mockito.anyInt(), Mockito.anyShort()));
```

But it throws exception, and I don't think it is what I actually need.

UPDATE

After a bit more reading it seems I have to use `PowerMockito.stub`, or `PowerMockito.supress`. So I have tried the following:

```java
PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(B.class, "veryAnnoyingMethod", int.class, short.class)).toReturn(null);
```

or

```java
PowerMockito.supress(PowerMockito.method(B.class, "veryAnnoyingMethod", int.class, short.class));
```

But with either the method is still executed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, I finally got it to work. Using either of `stub` and `suppress` is working. The test looks something like this:

```java
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(B.class)
class TestClassAWithPowerMockito{
    @Test
    public void testVeryImportantMethod() throws Exception {
        A a = new A();
        PowerMockito.suppress(PowerMockito.method(B.class, "veryAnnoyingMethod", int.class, short.class));
        a.veryImportantMethod();
        ...
    }
}
```

Note the `@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)` and `@PrepareForTest(B.class)`
I had to take the test using PowerMockito in separate class because adding these 2 notations made some of my other tests (which do not use PowerMockito, but only Mockito) fail.

Hope this is clear, and helps someone who is struggling with a similar problem.