# Mock method on a new instance

Tags: java, mockito, junit5

I am trying to create Junit test case using Mockito framework and junit5. I am working on the below code:

```
    Class ClasstToBeTested {
      FirstClass a = new FirstClass();

      public String methodToBeTested() {
         String str = a.firstMethod();
         return str;
      }
    }

   Class FirstClass {
      SecondClass b = new SecondClass();

      public String firstMethod() {
          String str = b.secondMethod();
          return str;
      }
   }
```

I have a class structure like above and I need to mock secondMethod.

I tried @spy on FirstClass and mocked SecondClass and secondMethod, but mocking didn't happen. How can I mock in this case?

Note - I am not in a position to change the structure of the class.

Comment: can you change the structure of your classes? mocking is not going to work this way, at least with `Mockito`.

Comment: They are being legacy, I will not be able to modify the class structure. Anything to do with Powermock ?

Comment: yeah, look into `PowerMock::whenNew`

Answer (score 1):

You have some options:

1. (Preferred) Use IoC dependency injection to supply the `SecondClass` instance instead of building it inside `FirstClass`:

```java
  class FirstClass {
      private final SecondClass b;

      // Injecting the SecondClass instance
      FistClass(SecondClass b) {
          this.b = b;
      }

      public String firstMethod() {
          String str = b.secondMethod();
          return str;
      }
   }
```

Then you can just inject a mock in your test.

2. Add a `SecondClass` setter just for tests.

```java
   class FirstClass {
      SecondClass b = new SecondClass();

      // Annotate with a visibility for test annotation if available.
      // Here one can inject a mock too, but can cause problems if used inadvertently.
      void setSecondClassForTests(SecondClass b) {
         this.b = b;
      }

      public String firstMethod() {
          String str = b.secondMethod();
          return str;
      }
   }
```

Then you call the setter on the test and pass the mock.

3. Use reflection to get the field and set a mock. Something like (In your test function):

```
final Field declaredField = instanceOfFirstClass.getClass().getDeclaredFields("b");
declaredField.setAccessible(true);
declaredField.set(instanceOfFirstClass, yourMockedInstance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest versions of mockito supports mocking contructors

Refer : [Mocking methods of local scope objects with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520242/mocking-methods-of-local-scope-objects-with-mockito/72595913#72595913)

Your code being tested should work from scratch without requiring any modification. You have to use the mockito's mockConstructor method in the test case code correctly for this to work.

Comment: Please clarify if this means that OP's code should work from scratch or if any modification is required (in which case, please give an example)

Comment: Code being tested should work from scratch without requiring any modification.
But he has to use the mockito's mockConstructor method in his test case code correctly for this to work

Comment: Please add this information directly in the answer for future readers